# Java socket fail to send data to server

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I am writing a java socket program used to send JSON object from a client to another client. Now, I am just testing it by sending string data which is input by console. When I type something in console and send it to server, the server should print that out and send it back to client, then client should print that out as well. But my server program doesn't show anything in console, neither does the client. I can't find where the problem is.

Server:

```
public class GameServer {
private Socket socket;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private ArrayList<GameServerThread> threads;

public GameServer(){
    try{
        //Create new server socket
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234,100);
        System.out.println("Waiting for clients ...");
        threads = new ArrayList<GameServerThread>();
        //Receive request from client
        while(true){
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            //Create new Thread once receive a request
            new Thread(new GameServerThread(socket, this)).start();     
        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Failed to create socket!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}   



public ArrayList<GameServerThread> getAllThreads(){
    return this.threads;
}


public void addNewThread(GameServerThread t){
    this.threads.add(t);
}



public static void main(String args[]){
    GameServer server = new GameServer();
}
}
```

ServerThread:

```
public class GameServerThread extends Thread{
private Socket socket;
private GameServer server;
private OutputStreamWriter writer;
private BufferedReader reader;
String userName;

public GameServerThread(Socket s, GameServer srv) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException{
    System.out.println("Succeeded to connect with one client!");
    this.socket = s;
    this.server = srv;
    writer = new OutputStreamWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));  
    this.server.addNewThread(this);
}


public void run(){
    try{
        while(true){
            receive();
        }
    }catch(SocketException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{       
        try {
            this.socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


private void receive() throws IOException{
    String str = null;
    while((str=reader.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(str);
        sendToOther(str);       }
}


public void send(String msg){
    try{
        writer.write(msg);
        writer.flush();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void sendToOther(String msg){
    for(GameServerThread thread: this.server.getAllThreads()){
        //if(!thread.equals(this)){
            thread.send(msg);
        //}
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class GameClient {
private Socket socket;
private String serverIP;
private OutputStreamWriter writer;
private BufferedReader reader;

public GameClient(String host){
    this.serverIP = host;

    try{
        //Connect to server
        socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 1234);
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        //Start a new thread for reading from server
        new Thread(new GameClientThread(socket)).start();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write something: ");
        String str = "";
        while((str = scanner.nextLine()) != null){
            writer.write(str);
            writer.flush();
            System.out.println("Write something: ");
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Client failed to connect!");
        e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Client Thread:

```
public class GameClientThread extends Thread{
private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader reader;

//private OutputStreamWriter writer;
//private String userName = "";

public GameClientThread(Socket soc){
    this.socket = soc;

    try{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (this.socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


public void run(){
    while(true){
        receive();
    }
}


private void receive(){
    String msg;
    try {
        msg = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(msg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"Here's a bunch of my code, it doesn't work, can someone help me figure it out"_ are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information, and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BufferedReader.readLine expects a new line (\n, \r or \r\n) at the end of every line, but you don't write a new line when you're writing data. Add a `writer.write('\n');` every time that you write a string that doesn't already end in a new line.

Comment: What does "stunting data" mean?

Comment: @Jim thanks. Don't you love mobile phone autocorrect...